# How to release Drawable in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to preview all the `drawable` resources in my system, so I create a `ListView`, and get the `drawables` with `getView()`. It works well at the beginning, but when I preview about 1000 pictures,
an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs.

**Why are these `drawables` not released?**

I don't have other references in the code; and can I release them myself?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageItemView view;
    ImageItem item = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = (ImageItemView) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.image_item, null);
    }else{
        view = (ImageItemView) convertView;
    }
    Drawable draw ;

    try{
        draw = mRes.getDrawable(item.getid());
        view.setIcon(draw);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {

    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: There are no ImageItemView and ImageItem classes in the SDK,  so nobody knows what classes you are using, android_labs_rw? Or any other?

Comment: Use view holder will help: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung No, View Holders will not help

Comment: use bitmaps for it can be recycled. i dont know if drawables can be released in this case.

Comment: I have tested ViewHolders, the error still existed.